# NetworkX related warning when running Memgraph v2.8.0 in WSL installed using binary for Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: memgraphdb

I get NetworkX related warning when running Memgraph v2.8.0 in WSL installed using binary for Ubuntu 22.04

Once I start Memgraph, they I see this:

`Please install networkx to be able to use wcc module. Using Python: 3.10.6 (main, May 29 2023, 11:10:38) [GCC 11.3.0] NOTE: Please install networkx to be able to use graph_analyzer module. Using Python: 3.10.6 (main, May 29 2023, 11:10:38) [GCC 11.3.0] NOTE: Please install networkx, numpy, scipy to be able to use proxied NetworkX algorithms. E.g., CALL nxalg.pagerank(...). Using Python: 3.10.6 (main, May 29 2023, 11:10:38) [GCC 11.3.0] NOTE: Please install networkx to be able to use Memgraph NetworkX wrappers. Using Python: 3.10.6 (main, May 29 2023, 11:10:38) [GCC 11.3.0]`

I've tried to use Memgraph docker image, and I don't see this error.

What should I do to avoid this warning when I run Memgraph using WSL2 on Windows 11 machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a warning when these packages are not installed (Memgraph when loading query modules can’t fine these packages. Memgraph will work, except the modules using NetworkX won’t work.

The solution is to install the listed python packages globally on the system where Memgraph is started, or locally for the user which is running Memgraph.